# Create index on select count(*) from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I have a table "Table" and I use the select count statement on it in many times...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table;
```

I want create a clustered index on it. How can I create it? thx

Comment: If your table has a primary key you already have a clustered index on it. Otherwise `create index` is documented in the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: I think a non-clustered index might actually be faster for this as it will be a lot smaller (and thus less I/O necessary).

Comment: For the sake of completeness, a primary key can be supported by both clustered and nonclustered index. Deafult is clustered, but it's overridable, and it actually doesn't matter as long it's unique (and not filtered and not null).

Answer (score 0):

For the efficient `COUNT(*)` create the narrowest nonclustered index you can, ie a nonclustered index on the smallest not-null column.

This was easy, but I'm actually more puzzled why would you have a lot of `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries. It could be that you're misusing it instead of EXISTS clause? The optimizer actually recognizes this pattern in most cases, but why not help him?